# how to do this in X rather than +

Tags: javascript

So This makes it so every level from 1-30 will be 17 exp + 3 more after each level but i wanted to do the same thing but in Times (x) rather than adding 3 every level.

````
    if (level > 30) {
        var exp = 17;
        level -= 30;
        for (var i = 1; i <= level; i++) {
            exp += 17 + (i * 3);```
````

Comment: what about level >30 and what does  level -= 30; do

Comment: you could replace the `for` loop with `exp += (17 + (i * 3)) * level`

Comment: I suggest to give a better explanation of what you are trying to approach, you can use `edit` link under your question...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var exp;

function Times(x) {
  if (x > 30) {
    exp = 17;
  x-=30
     for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    exp += 17 + (i * 3);
  }
}
return exp;
}
console.log(Times(45))
```